# Set intersection of n number in Python loop

Tags: python, loops, set, intersection

I have 4 lists:

```
l1 = ['one', 'two', 'three']
l2 = ['one', 'six', 'three']
l3 = ['one', 'four', 'five']
l4 = ['one', 'three','five']
```

in order to find common intersection of all four lists I would do:

```
inter = set(l1).intersection(l2).intersection(l3).intersection(l4)
```

> :return: {'one'}

How can I achieve the same with n number of lists in a list?

```
list_of_lists = [l1, l2, l3, l4]
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Use a list of sets:

```
check_list = list(set(l) for l in (l2, l3, l4))
```

Then loop:

```
result = set(l1)
for s in check_list:
    result = result.intersection(s)
print(result)
```

Other option is to use `reduce`:

```
check_list = list(set(l) for l in (l1, l2, l3, l4))
from functools import reduce
result = reduce(set.intersection, check_list)
```

Here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/repls/StaleIntelligentTrees)